# Install multiple tomcat 7 servers on single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I am building a tomcat cluster on an EC2 instance... I'm using the Amazon Linux AMI so I used "yum install tomcat7" to install tomcat... I need to install another copy of tomcat.. yum puts files all over the place, not to mention the tomcat startup script. Is there an easy way to setup another instance without having to duplicate all those files by hand?

Comment: There is a per-service configuration file template at /etc/sysconfig/tomcat. Refer to the comment at the top of the file for instructions on setting up multiple Tomcat services on one Amazon Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't use YUM then.

Simply download the tomcat from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

After downloading, you can out it anywhere you want, like `/usr/local/` or `/opt/`, where ever you want.

And then use the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the jpackage-repo, it resolves all of the dependencies for tomcat7.
Install the rpm from this page to make installing the yum repo easy: http://jpackage.org/browser/rpm.php?jppversion=5.0&id=8559

Answer (score 0):

you could try using multiple tomcat docker continers.
https://hub.docker.com/r/uday1kiran/tomcatserver